# How to return a transformed object from a Firebase observable, where a nested value must be returned from another Firebase observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, observable

As per the title, I'm retrieving a member's profile from Firebase using the `database.object` method and subscribing to that in the profile view controller of an Angular 4 app.

At present, I can get all of that profile info just fine, and the data is mutated in my Firebase controller.

For some background:

- Inside my profile object, there's an ID of an admin user which was responsible for some updates to the profile
- Using that ID, I need to grab a user object from Firebase, which contains things like the admin user's name who made the change

Here's a reduced example of what I'm doing:

**firebase.controller.ts**

```
public getMemberProfile(id: string): Observable < IProfile > {
  return this.database.object(`${MEMBERS_PATH}/${id}`).map(member => this.transformMember(member))
}

public getAdminUser(id: string): Observable < IUser > {
  return this.database.object(`${USERS_PATH}/${id}`).map(user => user)
}

private transformMember(member): IProfile {
  return {
    aboutUserObj: this.getAdminUser(member.adminUserId).subscribe((adminUser)=> {
      return adminUser // Of course this does NOT work
    }),
   // Other stuff
  }
}
```

**profile.controller.ts**

```
this.memberFirebase.getMemberProfile(this.id).subscribe((profile) => {
  this.profile = profile
})
```

As you can hopefully see from the reduced case, it is a prerequisite that I load the member, then use the member object to get the ID I need to get the admin user I need to include to list updates to this profile in the view.

**The question**

How do I successfully load the member and then subsequently additional user info from Firebase in order to return that all as one observable which contains the complete, mutated profile?

*I'm particularly interested in knowing what 'best practice' might look like for this kind of scenario.*

Thanks in advance! I hope this is clear enough, if not please feel free to suggest ameliorations.

Comment: Go through the problem but still not clear , what do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like flatMap so you can chain the observables

```
this.getMemberProfile(id).flatMap(
    res => {
        // get id from res of first observable
        let adminId = res.id;

        return this.getAdminUser(adminId);
    }
)
.map(res => {
    // do other transformation as needed
    return res;
})
```

Then you would subscribe to this chained observable sequence.

Here is a good resource on flatMap https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: Excellent, just the ticket. I've implemented this in a roundabout way and it works expectedly. Thank you! Here's hoping this can help somebody else experimenting with observables :)